# What is the difference between the Airflow http sensor and just calling the endpoint on a scheduled DAG?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have an Airflow DAG that needs to be triggered every time I get a specific response from a REST endpoint. I need to check this endpoint in a specific interval (a couple of minutes). I have been investigating how to implement this and found two different approaches:

1. implementing an http sensor and polling the endpoint until the condition is met,

or

2. just schedule my DAG to run every 2 minutes and check the http endpoint in the first task of my DAG.

My question is, what would be the difference between these 2 approaches? My guess is, 1) the DAG is always running while the sensor calls the endpoint every X seconds, while 2) the DAG invocation finishes if the response from the API is negative.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The first approach seems more logical:***

- In version 2 of Airflow, [smart sensors](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/smart-sensor.html) have been added and it is possible to **execute long-running tasks more optimally**.
- Continuous execution of a workflow (Option 2) **causes many records to be inserted into the internal Airflow database**, which will require a separate workflow to clear the database.
- The **first method is closer to the logic of this work**.

I personally prefer the first method.